# How to execute a python file (.py) on hadoop distributed file system (hdfs)

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

Hadoop offers the possibility to run java applications directly on the cluster using

```
hadoop jar <jar>
```

Now I have a python script instead of a java application.

Below is the construct of the .py file without the all the functionality, just left the "remove-files-from-folder" part

```
import os.path

def transform():
    inputfolder = "input"
    for filename in os.listdir(inputfolder):
        path = inputfolder + "\\" + filename
        os.remove(path)
def main():
    transform()
if __name__ == "__main__":  main()
```

Is there a way to execute the .py file similarly to the way I'd execute a .jar file?

I'm new to Python and Hadoop. If my approach seems totally off and doesn't make sense, I'm happy for any kind of clarification!

Comment: `hadoop jar` is specifically for running MapReduce jobs. It looks like you want to manipulate files on the HDFS using Python? In which case you should look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply looking to distribute your python script across the cluster then you want to use Hadoop Streaming.

The basic syntax of the command looks like (from https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html):

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-input myInputDirs \
-output myOutputDir \
-mapper myPythonScript.py \
-file myPythonScript.py
```

This basically creates a map-reduce job for your python script

Comment: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/ offers a nice tutorial on this.

Comment: Thanks, it got me on the right track. I will need to adjust my python script to work as a MapReduce job.

Comment: No problem Rob, just remember Hadoop streaming with python works by pulling in stdin and outputting stdout.